Build a nonholonomic mobile manipulator using RBDL?
How to build a nonholonomic mobile manipulator using RBDL? something like this:
my code is:
  std::unique_ptr<RigidBodyDynamics::Model> rbdl_robot =
      std::make_unique<RigidBodyDynamics::Model>();
  RigidBodyDynamics::Addons::URDFReadFromFile(
      "robot.urdf",
      rbdl_robot.get(), true, false);
  std::cout << "Model Hierarchy:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << RigidBodyDynamics::Utils::GetModelHierarchy(*rbdl_robot)
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Degree of freedoms overview: " << rbdl_robot->dof_count
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Q Dofs: " << rbdl_robot->q_size
            << ", QD Dofs: " << rbdl_robot->qdot_size << std::endl;
  std::cout << RigidBodyDynamics::Utils::GetModelDOFOverview(*rbdl_robot)
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Rbdl dofs: " << rbdl_robot->dof_count << std::endl;

I set the floating base to true, which caused the problem that the base had six degrees of freedom. I only want it to have two degrees of freedom, translation along the x direction and rotation along the z direction.
How should I modify it?
urdf:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- ============================================================================================== -->
<!-- |                                                                                            | -->
<!-- |    baxter.urdf is DEPRECATED. It is included here for backward compatibility.              | -->
<!-- |    Please use baxter.urdf.xacro by running:                                                | -->
<!-- |$ rosrun xacro xacro.py - -inorder `rospack find baxter_description`/urdf/baxter.urdf.xacro | -->
<!-- |                                                                                            | -->
<!-- ============================================================================================== -->
<robot name="baxter">
  <material name="Black">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Blue">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.8 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Light_blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.4 0.8 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Green">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Grey">
    <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Orange">
    <color rgba="1.0 0.4235294117647059 0.0392156862745098 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Brown">
    <color rgba="0.8705882352941177 0.8117647058823529 0.7647058823529411 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="Red">
    <color rgba="0.8 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <material name="White">
    <color rgba="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
  </material>
  <link name="iiwa_link_0">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.1 0 0.07"/>
      <mass value="5"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.06" iyz="0" izz="0.03"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_0.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_0.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </collision>
    <self_collision_checking>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.25" radius="0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </self_collision_checking>
  </link>
  <!-- joint between link_0 and link_1 -->
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_1" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_0"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.15"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-2.9670597283903604" upper="2.9670597283903604" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-2.9321531433504737" soft_upper_limit="2.9321531433504737"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 -0.03 0.12"/>
      <mass value="3.4525"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.02183" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.007703" iyz="-0.003887" izz="0.02083"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.0075"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.0075"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_2" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_1"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_2"/>
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966   0 3.141592653589793" xyz="0 0 0.19"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-2.0943951023931953" upper="2.0943951023931953" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-2.0594885173533086" soft_upper_limit="2.0594885173533086"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0003 0.059 0.042"/>
      <mass value="3.4821"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.02076" ixy="0" ixz="-0.003626" iyy="0.02179" iyz="0" izz="0.00779"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_3" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_2"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_3"/>
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0 3.141592653589793" xyz="0 0.21 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-2.9670597283903604" upper="2.9670597283903604" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-2.9321531433504737" soft_upper_limit="2.9321531433504737"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_3">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0.03 0.13"/>
      <mass value="4.05623"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.03204" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.00972" iyz="0.006227" izz="0.03042"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.026"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.026"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_4" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_3"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_4"/>
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.19"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-2.0943951023931953" upper="2.0943951023931953" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-2.0594885173533086" soft_upper_limit="2.0594885173533086"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_4">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0.067 0.034"/>
      <mass value="3.4822"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.02178" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.02075" iyz="-0.003625" izz="0.007785"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_5" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_4"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_5"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 3.141592653589793 0" xyz="0 0.21 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-2.9670597283903604" upper="2.9670597283903604" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-2.9321531433504737" soft_upper_limit="2.9321531433504737"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_5">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0001 0.021 0.076"/>
      <mass value="2.1633"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01287" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.005708" iyz="-0.003946" izz="0.01112"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.026"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.026"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_6" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_5"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_6"/>
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="0 0.06070 0.19"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-2.0943951023931953" upper="2.0943951023931953" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-2.0594885173533086" soft_upper_limit="2.0594885173533086"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_6">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0.0006 0.0004"/>
      <mass value="2.3466"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.006509" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.006259" iyz="0.00031891" izz="0.004527"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Orange"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_7" type="revolute">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_6"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_7"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 3.141592653589793 0" xyz="0 0.081 0.06070"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="300" lower="-3.0543261909900763" upper="3.0543261909900763" velocity="10"/>
    <safety_controller k_position="100" k_velocity="2" soft_lower_limit="-3.01941960595019" soft_upper_limit="3.01941960595019"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.5"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_7">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.02"/>
      <mass value="3.129"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01464" ixy="0.0005912" ixz="0" iyy="0.01465" iyz="0" izz="0.002872"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.0005"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/visual/link_7.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.0005"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://dog_dual_arm/meshes/iiwa7/collision/link_7.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Grey"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- ee_link: virtual -->
  <joint name="iiwa_joint_ee" type="fixed">
    <parent link="iiwa_link_7"/>
    <child link="iiwa_link_ee"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.045"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="iiwa_link_ee">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.0001"/>
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="car_arm_fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_car"/>
     <child link="iiwa_link_0"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.1"/>
  </joint>

  <!-- car -->
<!-- car -->
  <link name="base_car">
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.0 1.0 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.0 1.0 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="70.00"/>
      <inertia ixx="6.7667" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="6.7667" iyz="0.0" izz="11.6667"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>


  <link name="right_wheel_link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="4"/>
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="right_wheel_joint_1" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_car"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="-0.4 0.525 -0.1"/>
    <child link="right_wheel_link_1"/>
    <limit effort="99999" lower="-1E16" upper="1E16" velocity="13.299408900196791"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="right_wheel_link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="4"/>
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="right_wheel_joint_2" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_car"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.4 0.525 -0.1"/>
    <child link="right_wheel_link_2"/>
    <limit effort="99999" lower="-1E16" upper="1E16" velocity="13.299408900196791"/>
  </joint>



  <link name="left_wheel_link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="4"/>
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="left_wheel_joint_1" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_car"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="-0.41 -0.525 -0.1"/>
    <child link="left_wheel_link_1"/>
    <limit effort="99999" lower="-1E16" upper="1E16" velocity="13.299408900196791"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="left_wheel_link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="4"/>
      <inertia ixx="0" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0" iyz="0" izz="0"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="left_wheel_joint_2" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_car"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.4 -0.525 -0.1"/>
    <child link="left_wheel_link_2"/>
    <limit effort="99999" lower="-1E16" upper="1E16" velocity="13.299408900196791"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

